# Will changing app executable file name between app store versions cause a crash?

Tags: iphone, ios4

My team is planning a large upgrade of our app.  Since our last app store submission, we have changed the executable binary file name.  This was among several changes to make naming conventions make more sense.

When upgrading our app via Xcode (installing and replacing the old app), we see a very unusual "crash" upon launching it that seems to be on the OS side.  There is no app crash log, but see this in the device console:
1) "Application 'XXXXX' exited abnormally with exit status 1" and
2) "posix_spawn("/xxxx/yyy/zz"): Permission denied"

If I rename the executable and target back to what the app store version uses and repeat the upgrade process, I don't see this crash and the app runs normally.

Our concern here is that upon submitting our app to the store, any user who downloads it will experience a crash too and have to delete & re-download the app.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Has anyone successfully submitted an app with a modified executable binary file name and not seen any problems with users upgrading?

As a developer I think everything will be FINE, but I need some evidence that there won't be an issue to present to my product manager.  We have a lot of users paying us money that could be upset by this :)

Comment: Hi, Dan. Did you ever find an answer for this question? The company I work for is now going through this process of changing executable names as well, and I am unsure if there will be any issues when submitting to Apple for review. Thanks!